# I can't get parent in child component

Tags: ember.js

I am new in ember js. And I am trying to repeat this

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-communicate-to-child-components/7772/7

```
{{#my-super-form as |parent|}}
   {{some-child notify=parent}}
{{/my-super-form}}
```

And I always get

Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).send is not a function

in

```
this.get('notify').send('somethingHappened');
```

Why?..

I use ember 1.12

And where can I read about params in **yield**, for example

{{yield **param1 param2**}}

Answer (score 0):

I have found all answers here

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html

in my **my-super-form.hbs** need to use

```
{{yield this}}
```